# Get query data in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to get only matched data from the mongoDB database if I send following request from the postman:

```
{
    "city":"Bowie",
    "startTime": "2022-07-20 10:00",
    "duration":{
        "days":"0",
        "hours":"3",
        "minutes":10
    }
}
```

Here I am sending date of 20-july 2022 which falls on wednesday so I should see only that days parking availability but instead I am getting all the results like below

```
{
  "merchantId": {
    "$oid": "62c950dfc96c2b690028be88"
  },
  "contactInfo": {
    "name": "Claudia Shields",
    "phoneNumber": 8904672101
  },
  "location": {
    "address": "737 applegate court",
    "city": "bowie",
    "state": "rhode island",
    "country": "greece",
    "zipCode": 10825
  },
  "price": 16,
  "parkingType": "residence",
  "parkingInfo": [
    {
      "parkingName": "Fountain Avenue",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d12053cb03235286511d55"
      },
      "default": []
    }
  ],
  "totalSpots": [
    127
  ],
  "coordinates": {
    "lng": 34.048954,
    "lat": 10.299556
  },
  "status": "active",
  "isFeePaid": false,
  "parkingZone": [],
  "availability": [
    {
      "day": "Saturday",
      "startTime": "09:00",
      "endTime": "14:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13355bd1ad85d85ae4b4b"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Monday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13375bd1ad85d85ae4b4f"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Tuesday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d1337cbd1ad85d85ae4b53"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Wednesday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13383bd1ad85d85ae4b57"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Thursday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13390bd1ad85d85ae4b5b"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Friday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13396bd1ad85d85ae4b5f"
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

I think there is no relation into the database to identify the available days like Wednesday is day no. 3 if we calculate days in week

Here is the query to retrieve data

```
exports.getParkingListByCriteria = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    endTime = getEndTime(req.body.startTime, req.body.duration);
    console.log(`endTime: ${endTime}`);

    let parkings = await Parking.find({
      "location.city": req.body.city,
    });

    const parkingList = [];

    parkings.filter((parking) => {
      isParkingAvailable(parking.availability, req.body.startTime, endTime);
    });

    res.status(200).send(parkings);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

Here is the `isParkingAvailable` function:

```
exports.isParkingAvailable = (availability, startTime, endTime) => {
  let startDay = dayjs(startTime).day();
  console.log(`startDay -> ${startDay}`);
  let endDay = dayjs(endTime).day();
  console.log(`endDay -> ${endDay}`);

  let isStartAvailable = false;
  let isEndAvailable = false;

  startTimeOnly = dayjs(startTime).format("HH:mm");
  console.log(`startTimeOnly -> ${startTimeOnly}`);

  endTimeOnly = dayjs(endTime).format("HH:mm");
  console.log(`endTimeOnly -> ${endTimeOnly}`);

  availability.forEach((availabilityObject) => {
    if (startDay == availabilityObject.day) {
      if (
        availabilityObject.startTime <= startTimeOnly &&
        availabilityObject.endTime >= startTimeOnly,
        console.log("availabilityObject.startTime ->",availabilityObject.startTime)
        ) {
        isStartAvailable = true;
      }
    }
    if (endDay == availabilityObject.day) {
      if (
        availabilityObject.startTime >= endTimeOnly &&
        availabilityObject.endTime <= endTimeOnly
      ) {
        isEndAvailable = true;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

If I log the `req.body` in `isParkingAvailable` function then I am getting following data

```
startDay -> 3
endDay -> 3
startTimeOnly -> 10:00
endTimeOnly -> 13:10
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16462950/heiko-thei%c3%9fen . I apologize for tagging you in this but you are kind of helping me so can you please solve this?

Comment: `parkings.filter` does not operate "in place", therefore you must write `parkings = parkings.filter(...)`.

Comment: Done that, not working @HeikoTheißen

Comment: Your function `isParkingAvailable` does not return anything.

Comment: yup, that was a mistake I have corrected that @HeikoTheißen

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. What I have done is:

```
parkingData = parkings.filter((parking) => {
  if (isParkingAvailable(parking.availability, req.body.startTime, endTime))
    isParkingAvailable(parking.availability);
  parkingList.push(parking);
});
```